# Change the value of each cell that meets criteria in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the value of each cell in column 7 that meets criteria. So far I managed to change the value with one criteria but I would like to add up to 14 criteria. Thanks for your help

```
Sub ChangeValue()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim WK As Worksheet
    Dim rg1 As range
    Dim rg2 As range

    Set WK = Sheet4
    Set rg1 = range("AB2")
    Set rg2 = range("AB3")

    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 7).Value = rg1 Then
            Cells(i, 7).Value = rg2.Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I would like to have more conditions something like if = AB3 change to AB4 if= AB4 Change to AB5 and so on...

Comment: There are functions in Excel that allows you to take a cell relative to another cell, example "2 rows down". Make that a loop with a variable, compare and break loop when match is found. Allows you to have up to 2,7 mio conditions in column "AB"

Answer (score 0):

To create a variable list of value/replace value pairs I would suggest using a dictionary:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeValue()


  Dim d
  Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  
  Dim r_test_value As Range
  Dim r_anchor As Range
  Set r_anchor = Range("AB2")
  
  
  'need at least 2 values
  If Not IsEmpty(r_anchor) And Not IsEmpty(r_anchor.Offset(1, 0)) Then
    Set r_test_value = Range(r_anchor, _
        Cells(Rows.Count, r_anchor.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0))
    
    Debug.Print r_test_value.Address
  
 
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In r_test_value
      d.Add r.Value, r.Offset(i+1, 0).Value
      i = i + 1
    Next r
  
  
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
      If d.exists(Cells(i, 7).Value) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = d.Item(Cells(i, 7).Value)
      End If
    Next i
  
  End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Search and Replace Cell Values

**EDIT**

- This is a more appropriate solution.
- Adjust the starting rows i.e. `For i = ?` and `For k = ?`

**Second Answer**

```
Sub replaceValues()
 
    ' Determine Source Last Row.
    Dim sLastRow As Long
    sLastRow = Sheet4.Cells(Sheet4.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Determine Destination Last Row.
    Dim dLastRow As Long
    dLastRow = Sheet4.Cells(Sheet4.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long ' Destination Range Rows Counter
    Dim k As Long ' Source Rows Counter
    ' Loop through rows of Destination Range.
    For i = 2 To dLastRow
        ' Loop through rows of Source Range.
        For k = 1 To sLastRow - 1
            ' When a value is found...
            If Sheet4.Cells(i, "G").Value = Sheet4.Cells(k, "AB").Value Then
                ' ... replace it with the value below.
                Sheet4.Cells(i, "G").Value = Sheet4.Cells(k + 1, "AB").Value
                Exit For ' Value has been found and replaced. Stop searching.
                ' Otherwise you'll end up with the last replace value.
            End If
        Next k
    Next i
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Values replaced.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

**The First Answer (misunderstood)**

- The first solution is for using worksheet code names. It can be used for two worksheets. It is one in your case (`Sheet4`).
- The second solution shows how to use it in two worksheets using worksheet names.
- The code will loop through a column range of values and replace each value found in a row range of 'search values' with an associated 'replace value' in another same sized row range (in this case the ranges are adjacent, one below the other).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub replaceValuesWorksheetCodeNames()
    
    ' Source
    ' Make sure the following two are of the same size.
    Const srcAddress As String = "AB2:AO2"
    Const rplAddress As String = "AB3:AO3"
    ' Destination
    Const dFirstCell As String = "G2"
    
    ' Write Source Row Ranges to Source Arrays (Search and Replace).
    With Sheet4
        Dim srcData As Variant: srcData = .Range(srcAddress).Value
        Dim rplData As Variant: rplData = .Range(rplAddress).Value
    End With
    
    ' Define Destination Column Range.
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim RowOffset As Long
    With Sheet4.Range(dFirstCell)
        RowOffset = .Row - 1
        Set rg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - RowOffset) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(rg.Row - RowOffset)
    End With
    
    ' Write values from Destination Column Range to Data Array.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rCount > 1 Then
        Data = rg.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Search and replace values in Data Array.
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rCount
        cValue = Data(i, 1)
        If Not IsError(cValue) Then
            If Len(cValue) > 0 Then
                cIndex = Application.Match(cValue, srcData, 0)
                If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                    ' When the replace data is in a row range.
                    Data(i, 1) = rplData(1, cIndex)
                    ' When the replace data is in a column range.
                    'Data(i, 1) = rplData(cIndex, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
        
    ' Write possibly modified values from Data Array back
    ' to Destination Column Range.
    rg.Value = Data
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Values replaced.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub


Sub replaceValuesWorksheetNames()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    ' Make sure the following two are of the same size.
    Const srcAddress As String = "AB2:AO2"
    Const rplAddress As String = "AB3:AO3"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirstCell As String = "G2"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write Source Row Ranges to Source Arrays (Search and Replace).
    With wb.Worksheets(sName)
        Dim srcData As Variant: srcData = .Range(srcAddress).Value
        Dim rplData As Variant: rplData = .Range(rplAddress).Value
    End With
    
    ' Define Destination Column Range.
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim RowOffset As Long
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirstCell)
        RowOffset = .Row - 1
        Set rg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - RowOffset) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(rg.Row - RowOffset)
    End With
    
    ' Write values from Destination Column Range to Data Array.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rCount > 1 Then
        Data = rg.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Search and replace values in Data Array.
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rCount
        cValue = Data(i, 1)
        If Not IsError(cValue) Then
            If Len(cValue) > 0 Then
                cIndex = Application.Match(cValue, srcData, 0)
                If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                    ' When the replace data is in a row range.
                    Data(i, 1) = rplData(1, cIndex)
                    ' When the replace data is in a column range.
                    'Data(i, 1) = rplData(cIndex, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
        
    ' Write possibly modified values from Data Array back
    ' to Destination Column Range.
    rg.Value = Data
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Values replaced.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention but that i am totally new to VBA and trying to learn by watching videos on youtube. the suggested codes left me totally lost. Just to clarify what i would like to achieve if that helps; My criteria are in sheet4 ranges, AB2, AB3 up to AB14. So in Column 7 of sheet4 i want to look at each cell and if it matches a criteria then replace it value to the criteria above. I mean if a cell  equals to range AB2 be changed to AB3, AB3 to AB4, AB4 to AB5, AB5 to AB6, AB6 to AB7, AB7 to AB8, AB8 to AB9,and AB 13  will be AB14. Again thanks for your assistance.

Comment: So the replacements are kind of shifted. No problem. I'll look into it and try to post a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Yes, are shifted in fact I am promoting student from one class to another so criteria ranges are the different classes 1-14. I will wait for the post.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a new solution at the top of the post.

Comment: You solved it ! Thank you loads. Just in case it is not much trouble for you i just posted another on named range if you could look at it. Thank you one more time